# Is the number of days with the daily rep limit reached shown somewhere?

Tags: support, reputation

There are badges for certain numbers (50?) of days on which you have reached the daily limit of 200 rep points. Is there an easy way to see how many such days have been there for you? For many badges in the "you need some more of this" category (e.g. Reviewer, Steward, tag badges) you are shown precisely (and prominently) how much you have and need yet. For the "copy editor" you have to click a few times but can see your current status then.

Counting days in the reputation diagram seems unpleasant to me.

BTW: I noticed that the ratio of rep points to badges is quite different among the users. If you look at the page with the most rep users then you find several cases (including me) where users on consecutive positions differ in badges by a factor of two. I wouldn't be surprised about that with low-rep users because you "have to" want certain badges in order to get them. But I would expect this difference to become much smaller at higher rep numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the /reputation path there's an entry at the end that tells you:

> rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 4 days

But the one you are looking for is:

> earned at least 200 reputation on 4 days

https://unix.stackexchange.com/reputation